# Login vs Logon?

Tags: grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logging in or on?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/logging-in-or-on)
>   [“log in to” or “log into” or “login to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to)

In computers, it seems like both login and logon are used. When I was taking some networking courses at the college, we were told to "Login to Windows", and "Logon to Novell". Is there really a difference?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This question is addressed [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33845/), among other places.

Comment: There are some nuances missing from all of those answers.  A *login* is a Unix term, whereas a *logon* sounds like it comes from some huge corporate behemoth like IBM or Microsoft.  Also, untechnical people now use the word in a way unrelated to authentication, and meaning only a connection. It is passing strange, a misapprehension that causes of needless confusion.