# Which is correct? log in, log on, log into, log onto

Tags: expressions, verbs, sentence, phrasal-verbs

I've seen different questions related to the same verb, but those questions implicate an imperative form (For example when you tell somebody to log in/on) which I think may vary the condition in which the verb is used.

> 1. He uses another program to log **in to** the system.
> 2. He uses another program to log **into** the system.
> 3. He uses another program to log **on to** the system.
> 4. He uses another program to log **onto** the system.

I think number 2 is correct but I'll wait for your suggestions.

Comment: You may find some useful answers in [this answered post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to) or [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/logging-in-or-on).

Comment: Use whatever preposition makes the metaphor work the best... Are you metaphorically “***in***” the system or “***on***” the system?  I’m more likely to be *in* a chatroom than *on* a chatroom. But I’m more likely to be *on* the master console than *in* the master console.

Comment: I have read that topic and 'notaverb.com/login'. They say login is not a verb. We can't conjugate it. However what about 'log in'?  He 'logs in' every day. He logged in yesterday. They say it still is not a verb but really I thought It came from 'log' (captain's log). You write in the log. So I thought the action itself was thought as log/v/ (logging). When I think about the action log in, I can totally relate into writing in a log (logging into a notebook, registering your name into somewhere). Comment section is not enough, got to many things I want to say and express myself better.

Comment: As a computer geek for 49 years, I prefer #1.  Especially since "login" as a noun is widely accepted in the industry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my money, log on to a system or log in to a system are interchangeable, and depend on the metaphor you are using (see comment on your post). I suppose there is a small bit of connotation that "log on" implies use, and "log in" implies access or a specific user.

Not to be confused with "login" - a noun describing a combination of username/password.

I'd pick 1) because the program is accessing a system (in vs. on), and "log in" is the action, whereas "to" begins the prepositional phrase.

So, he uses another program to log in to the system.