# Is that "log on" the website or "log onto" the website?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

Is that "log on" the website or "log onto" the website? What is a difference?

Comment: Or is it 'log in" to the website?

Comment: The action is 'logging on', but you log on _to_ a particular site (the same way as you open a book, but open it _at_ a particular page).

Comment: In any case there is generally no logging involved — other than someone stealing information about you. It’s a valid question what would be a better expression — “connect to” is also technically incorrect. Perhaps “access”.

Comment: If you said "log on the website" rather than "log on to the website" you would be suggesting the the website was, somehow, being logged on to something else, possibly some sort of verification service.

Comment: [Dupe of a dupe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290874/which-is-correct-log-in-log-on-log-into-log-onto?rq=1)